# column not allowed, ajax submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, oracle, coldfusion

What I have is a form for managing who gets notifications concerning another web app. It is very simple: add and delete who gets the notifications. On the delete field I have a jQuery autocomplete function, and on select it asks the user to confirm the deletion. If yes, it does a jQuery .ajax() call to my coldfusion file that deletes the user from the Oracle database. This function works as it should. On the add field, I have a jQuery .change() event that confirms the add. If yes, it should add the user email and an auto-incremented ID. This is where my problem is. I am getting a database error from the server and I don't know why. The syntax looks correct to me. I have used this syntax in other places in my app and it worked. Does anyone see my problem?

```
<cftry>
<cfif IsDefined('URL.theAction') && URL.theAction eq 'delete'>
    <cfquery name="qDeleteUser" datasource="#thedb#">
        DELETE
        FROM notify
        WHERE user_id = <cfqueryparam value="#URL.theID#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_NUMERIC">
    </cfquery>
<cfelse>
    <cfquery name="qAddUser" datasource="#thedb#">
        INSERT INTO notify (user_id, name)
        VALUES (seq_notifyid,
        <cfqueryparam value="#URL.theName#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">)
    </cfquery>
</cfif>
```

The catch produces this:

*error code*: 984

*message*: [Macromedia][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-00984: **column not allowed here**

*column*:0

*line*:9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I knew this would be something stupid. It would help if I actually auto-incremented the auto-increment field. (**.nextVal**
)

```
VALUES (seq_notifyid.nextVal,
```

Answer (score 1):

Closing brackets for `INSERT` statement missing in

```
<cfquery name="qAddUser" datasource="#thedb#">
        INSERT INTO notify (user_id, name)
        VALUES (seq_notifyid,
        <cfqueryparam value="#URL.theName#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">     
 </cfquery>
```

Comment: Sorry, it was right in my code. That was just my copy and paste error.